# Find the index of the equilibrium points of the system (Question on solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, dynamical-systems, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

I have the following system: 
$$\dot{x} = 2xy$$
$$\dot{y} = 3x^2-y^2$$

I have the following solution: The system has one equilibrium point at the origin. Let the curve $\Gamma$ surrounding the origin be the ellipse $x = \cos\theta$, $y = \sqrt{3}\sin\theta$ for $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$. Then 
$$\dot{x} = 2xy = \sqrt{3}\sin2\theta$$
$$\dot{y} = 3\cos2\theta$$

Then on $\Gamma$ 
$$\tan\phi = \sqrt{3}\tan[\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta].$$
As $\theta$ increases from $0$ to $2\pi$, $\phi$ decreases $0$ to $-4\pi$. Hence the index is 2.

My question about this solution is how do I see that as $\theta$ increases from $0$ to $2\pi$, $\phi$ decreases $0$ to $-4\pi$? I feel like this is a typo because at $\theta = 0$ isn't $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Any help and comments would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(this is not an answer)

Are you sure you know, what are you doing? You seem to think about the ellipse as about the solution, but it is just an assisting construct to further analysis of the field.

[image]

Comment: This was a solution in my solutions manual, I can find the index by using the isoclines but this was the argument presented in the manual and exactly what my question is on.

Comment: aren't there any references to index before this note?

Comment: Yes, it says to consider a closed curve around the EQ point and see how the angle of the vector field changes around the closed curve. Each complete rotation is one added to the index. There was an example that says $\tan\phi$ = $\tan2\theta$ and $\phi$ increases by $4\pi$ as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$. The angle of the vector field makes two full rotations around the curve giving an index of $2$.

Comment: that is exactly what I thought:)
You have to analyze the curve for $\theta$ from 0 to $2\pi$. The angle $\phi$ should be angle between the curve and the field. I think, you should compute with the direction of the curve(gradient) not with the position vector...

Comment: Yea I agree I was just thrown off by this solution and wanted some extra insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm 7 years late, here it is anyways. The following picture allows you to visualize why the index of the fixed point should be 2 (edit: the index is -2!).

[image]

Comment: breathtaking devotion!!

Comment: My picture was totally wrong!! I just corrected it hahaha. Now you really can see why the index is -2 :p

Comment: but thanks for the kind comment tho, I'll take it

Answer (score 0):

To add some formulas to the plots:

If one sets $$z=\sqrt3x+iy,$$ then $$\dot z=i\bar z^2,$$ which also allows to directly read off the index $-2$. The negative sign is due to the conjugation switching the orientation of any rotation around the origin, the value $2$ due to the square. The constant factor $i$ has no influence on the index.